# Meagre Sets: Algebra

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, baire-category

Let meagre subsets be defined as:
$A\text{ meagre}\iff A=\bigcup_{\lvert K\rvert\leq\aleph_0} A_k\text{ with }\overline{A_k}°=\varnothing$
Then it satisfies:
$B\subseteq A\text{ meagre}\Rightarrow B\text{ meagre}$
$A_k\text{ meagre}\Rightarrow\bigcup_{\lvert K\rvert\leq\aleph_0} A_k\text{ meagre}$

*Flipping this around, is it possible to define meagre subsets by these properties?*

Comment: That would give any family closed under subsets and countable unions. I don't think such a family is unique.

Comment: If you've ever seen a proof of  "countable union of countable sets is countable", then you are ready to prove the last one.

Comment: Mhh, you're right @StefanHamcke, that wouldn't even be related to any topology at all...

Comment: Well, one could ask if there is a topology such that a given family with these properties has precisely the meagre sets in it. Something like that.

Comment: @Stefan: Hah. I just wrote that into my answer! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, it is the most natural question that arises here. So that's not surprising ;-)

Comment: @StefanHamcke: Is it fine if I remove some questions of mine that seem obvious or trivial?

Comment: Well, the answer by Asaf showed that your question can interpreted in a meaningful way, even if that's not the intended meaning, so I wouldn't remove this question.

Comment: Freeze, even if the question ended up obvious or trivial, it doesn't mean it's a bad question. Your question is very natural to ask in mathematics, "can we turn it around?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a set $X$, we say that $I$ is a $\sigma$-ideal on $X$ if the following holds:

1. $I\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$, is not empty and $X\notin I$.
2. If $A\in I$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $B\in I$.
3. If for $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $A_n\in I$ then $\bigcup A_n\in I$. (If we weaken this just for finitely many, we have an ideal, without the $\sigma$.)

The meager sets form a $\sigma$-ideal. But so do the zero measure sets (in the Lebesgue measure, for example). So do the countable subsets of $X$, if $X$ is uncountable.

The properties that you suggest are exactly those of a $\sigma$-ideal, but those are not unique at all to meager sets.

---

One can extend this question and ask, given a $\sigma$-ideal $I$ on an uncountable set $X$, is there a topology where $I$ is exactly the meager sets of the topology?

Well, there is, but it's not a very exciting topology. We declare $\tau$ to be the topology $\{A\subseteq X\mid X\setminus A\in I\lor A=\varnothing\}$. Then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ as it includes $X$ and $\varnothing$, closed under finite (and countable) intersections and arbitrary unions (because it's closed under supersets).

Note now that given $A\subseteq X$ then $\overline{A}=X$ if and only if $A\notin I$ if and only if $\overline{A}\notin I$.

Moreover all the closed sets, except $X$, have an empty interior. Therefore a set is meager if and only if it is closed and not equal to $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The property "being a set" (not very demanding!) verifies:

$B\subset A$ is a set $\Rightarrow$ $B$ is a set.

$A_k\text{ is a set}\Rightarrow\bigcup_{\lvert K\rvert\leq\aleph_0} A_k\text{ is a set}$

Comment: What, I meant was define a family satisfying this algebra. But that gives an example of a trivial such family namely the power set itself...

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is meager, then there is a sequence of nowhere dense subsets $\{A_n\}$ such that $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Now $B=B\cap A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(B\cap A_n)$. We just need show that each $B\cap A_n$ is nowhere dense, and this will finish the proof for the first.

But we can show something a little more general. Let $A$ be nowhere dense and $B\subseteq A$. Then $B$ is nowhere dense. Proof: $B\subseteq A$ implies $\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A}$. And this implies $\overline{B}^\circ\subseteq\overline{A}^\circ=\varnothing$. Thus
$\overline{B}^\circ=\varnothing$. Thus $B$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, does it now?

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I misread the question. You want to go the other way.

Comment: The countable subsets of a topological space form a $\sigma$-ideal. And these elements need not be nowhere dense (take a discrete topology).